# DRM issues 15.04

Tags: firefox, wine, 15.04, google-chrome, flash

I am trying to watch NBC Sports on my Ubuntu machine. I currently have 15.04 installed. I have tried using both Chrome and Firefox. Chrome (updated) has flash 18, which is good. I've read though that it uses peppered flash, which prevents the drm from passing though giving the OK. So I gave up on Chrome a while back.

Firefox then blocked flash 17, and caused a great panic that made everyone switch to flash 18. Flash 18 apparently has better security. The problem? Flash stopped supporting ubuntu like years ago. I use to be able to get away with this, because NBC only required 11 or greater, but NOW they require 18 or greater.

Yes I've tried hal (hardware abstraction layer), yes I've removed all the ~/.adobe files, yes i've tried to re-install the plug-in. I've tried most if not all google(able) things, and I'm kind of at a loss for what to do. I've tried using wine, but I need to upgrade to Flash 18 within Wine, which appears impossible right now.

I guess my only two options are to either get Firefox to use Flash 18, or to get chrome to accept the DRM; neither of which I know how to do.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Try Pipelight:

http://pipelight.net/cms/installation.html

It's also a good way to get Silverlight for the occasional weirdo site that uses it.

In case you have problems, read advice on this page:

http://pipelight.net/cms/faqs/faq-most-common-problems.html

Comment: Yea I tried this, but silverlight is pretty slow.